# varnish3.0.2 rewrite the url howto

Tags: linux, http, rewrite, reverse-proxy, varnish

I have lots directories which have the same image "_a.png",like these:

```
/data/images/{a,b,c,d}
```

Because this, the varnish cache multiple copies.
Now I want to rewrite the urls to one,like this:

```
if (req.url ~ "/_pty.png$") {
set req.url="/images/a/_pty.png";
}
```

so I reload varnish  but it not work in right!
eg. I get the url, http://xx.com/images/c/_pty.png  ,with varnishlog I find it's no right,the
code above no effect!
how to set？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the URL like this:

```
if (req.url ~ "/_pty.png$") {
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/images/(.+)/_pty.png$", "/images/a/_pty.png");
}
```

This should work.
Fixed as requested in the comment.

Comment: hi，maybe i don't Speak clearly,I mean the urls like this:   **bold** `http://xx.com/images/c/_pty.png  or http://xx.com/images/b/_pty.png when i get them ,the url will rewrite to http://xx.com/images/a/_pty.png ` by the way way "set req.url=" don't effect! any differents?

Comment: ok. Fixed my answer. This should work.

Comment: Thanks . But I had done it   `if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|swf|jpeg|ico)$") {
           unset req.http.cookie;                                        #清除url中jpg等文件cookie
                if (req.url ~ "/_empty.png$") {
                        #set req.url="/images/mlogo/sze/_empty.png";
                set req.url=regsub(req.url,"^/images/mlogo/(.+)/_empty.png$","/images/mlogo/sze/_empty.png");
                   }
         }`  and it's also wrong

Comment: Are you sure that your URL is `http://ip_address/images/mlogo/sze/_empty.png` ?

Comment: Or there may be few other directories in between this ?

Comment: yes,I am sure the URL is `http://ip_address/images/mlogo/sze/_empty.png ` ,and there is no other directories in between them ,it like this varnish(192.168.1.10:80)-->nginx(192.168.1.11:80)

Comment: **`12 VCL_call     c recv lookup
   12 VCL_call     c hash
   12 Hash         c /images/mlogo/dw/_empty.png
   12 Hash         c images.xx.com
   12 VCL_return   c hash
   12 VCL_call     c miss fetch
   12 Backend      c 13 www www
   12 TTL          c 695673534 RFC 259200 -1 -1 1356743465 0 1356743464 1357002664 259200
   12 VCL_call     c fetch
   12 TTL          c 695673534 VCL 86400 -1 -1 1356743465 -0
   12 VCL_return   c deliver
   12 ObjProtocol  c HTTP/1.1`**   this is the log

Comment: Oh ... you are also changing the ip_address ... I thought just the URL ... is it true ?

Comment: yes,the ip_address i had change when i test! it like this images.xx.com

Comment: So, there are two things, one is URL rewrite, which we are doing above and other is host rewrite. Can you please be clear what all you are looking for and please explain completely. Most of the things you are adding later. Please update the question with complete details and let me know once it's done.

Comment: Hi, GeekRide,sorry for replies late.I got it,the reason is because I put the code : `if (req.url ~ "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|cio)$") { unset req.http.cookie; return (lookup);}` before the code ,`if (req.url ~ "/_pty.png$") {
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/images/(.+)/_pty.png$", "/images/a/_pty.png");
}`   ,so I delete it,and  it work fine now!  thanks. By the way ,can i use code like this ? `if (req.url ~ "/_pty.png$") {
set req.url="/images/a/_pty.png";
}`  to redirect the URL?.-:)

Comment: I am not sure Sola, as I haven't tried this, but I don't see a reason for this not to work. You can give it a try, and hopefully this should work.